# SQL Server 2008 joining two queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm overlooking something trivial here.  This query isn't for any reason in particular other than trying to practice joining two queries.  The errors that I get are

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'inner'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.
```

And the query is

```
select t.countyName, x.countyName
    from
    (

    SELECT DISTINCT Patient.patientid, tblStateCounties.countyName, Patient.countyCode
    FROM         Patient INNER JOIN
                          tblStateCounties ON Patient.stateCode = tblStateCounties.stateCode AND Patient.countyCode = tblStateCounties.countyCode
    WHERE     (Patient.patientage > 80)
    ) 
    inner join 
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT Patient.patientid, tblStateCounties.countyName, Patient.countyCode
    FROM         Patient INNER JOIN
                          tblStateCounties ON Patient.stateCode = tblStateCounties.stateCode AND Patient.countyCode = tblStateCounties.countyCode
    WHERE     (Patient.patientage < 80)
    ) as x on t.countyname=x.countyname
```

Comment: you forgot to set t alias in your first Inner join

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you forgot use **alias** in the first `subquery`.

Answer (score 3):

```
select t.countyName, x.countyName
from
(

     SELECT DISTINCT Patient.patientid, tblStateCounties.countyName, Patient.countyCode
     FROM         Patient 
     INNER JOIN tblStateCounties ON Patient.stateCode = tblStateCounties.stateCode 
                                 AND Patient.countyCode = tblStateCounties.countyCode
      WHERE     (Patient.patientage > 80)
) rsT
inner join 
(
      SELECT DISTINCT Patient.patientid, tblStateCounties.countyName, Patient.countyCode
      FROM         Patient 
      INNER JOIN tblStateCounties ON Patient.stateCode = tblStateCounties.stateCode   
                                 AND Patient.countyCode = tblStateCounties.countyCode
      WHERE     (Patient.patientage < 80)
) rsX on rsT.countyname=rsX.countyname
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
(
    SELECT DISTINCT Patient.patientid, tblStateCounties.countyName, Patient.countyCode
    FROM Patient INNER JOIN tblStateCounties
    ON Patient.stateCode = tblStateCounties.stateCode 
    AND Patient.countyCode = tblStateCounties.countyCode
    WHERE (Patient.patientage > 80)
) as t
```